# "Direction of Variation" between 3D Vectors based on Yaw and Pitch

Tags: vector-analysis, 3d

I am looking for a formula to get the relative direction that an object is turned in, in degrees, given a starting and finishing yaw and pitch. Suppose an object is facing forward with a yaw and pitch of [0,0]. If it were to turn straight up to a new orientation of [0,27] or [0,any number], the output would be 0. And if it were to turn left from [0,0] to [8,0] it would return 90. I have a full list of the basic-logic outputs [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYNCB.png). The calculation I'm thinking of would be independent of the magnitude of the difference so the ones in the chart could be replaced with any number and still yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

After asking around I was able to find that I was looking for the arc-tangent of the yaw and pitch differences.